# Problems with foreign key set by lastrowid. FK value changes to 'none'

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using Python3.4 with SQlite3.

I have 2 tables where one table2 contains a foreign key that is the primary key in table1

After an insert in Table1 I retrieve the last row ID in the method def createLog using:

newID = c.lastrowid

The newID contains the correct value. Next I pass newID to a new method (def enterLog) that inserts data into the table2 with the foreign key.

I have set up some test code and this result of newID after each insert into table1 can be seen as 12 and 13 in the results below.

When I call the next method, to insert these values (12 and 13) the value then becomes 'none'.

I suspect that I may not be getting an integer value in return but something related to an object.

Can anyone see where the issue here is?

Thank you

Adam

**This code calls the database code below**

```
`class ProcessingLog():

def newLog(self, fk_user_preferences, recipe_name='not defined', user_name='not defined', cycles_to_be_completed=0, message='not defined'):
    message = 'Cycles to be completed: ' + str(cycles_to_be_completed) + '/n' + message
    query.createLog(fk_user_preferences,recipe_name, user_name, message)

def newEntry(self, id, user_name, cycles_completed, status, message):
    query.enterLog(id, user_name, cycles_completed, status, message)

def viewLog(self, id):
    db_records = query.viewLog(id)
    for item in db_records:
        print(item)`
```

**This is the code interacting with the database**

```
class DataBase():

db_file_path = '...hidden...'

def __init__(self, db_file=db_file_path):
    self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)  # Connection will create db but not tables

def createLog(self, recipe_id=0, recipe_name='test log', user_name='no user name', message='no message'):
    time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    newID = 0
    c = self.db_connection.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO processing_log (fk_user_preferences, recipe_name, message, timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?);', (recipe_id, recipe_name, message, time_stamp))
    newID = c.lastrowid
    self.db_connection.commit()
    self.enterLog(newID, user_name, 0, 'READY', 'Log initiated.', time_stamp)
    print("ewID....", NewID)
    return newID

def enterLog(self, processing_log_id=0, user_name='test log', cycle_number=0, status='no status', message='no message', time_stamp=''):
    if time_stamp == '': # allow time_stamp to be passed in from above
        time_stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    c = self.db_connection.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO log_entry (fk_processing_log, user, cycle_number, status, message, timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);', (processing_log_id, user_name, cycle_number, status, message, time_stamp))
    self.db_connection.commit()

def viewLog(self, record_id):
    c = self.db_connection.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM processing_log WHERE primary_key = ?;', (record_id,))
    records = c.fetchall()
    return records

def viewLogEntries(self, record_id):
    c = self.db_connection.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM log_entry WHERE fk_processing_log = ?;', (record_id,))
    records = c.fetchall()
    return records

def viewAllLogEntries(self):
    c = self.db_connection.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM log_entry ;')
    records = c.fetchall()
    return records
```

**This is some test code**

```
Log = ProcessingLog()
last_id = Log.newLog(1, 'test recipe name', 'test user_name', 10, 'test log entry message')
test_last_id = last_id
print(" newEntry =========================")
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'WAIT', 'f-name, last-name', 0, 'Waiting for start... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name' 1, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'PAUSE', 'f-name, last-name', 2, 'Processing Paused... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
sleep(2)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RESUME', 'f-name, last-name', 2, 'Processing Resumed... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name', 3, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name'', 4, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name', 5, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', ''f-name, last-name'', 6, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', ''f-name, last-name'', 7, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'COMPLETE', ''f-name, last-name'', 7, 'Processing complete... ')
print("last_id.....",test_last_id)
last_id = Log.newLog(2, 'test2 recipe name', 'test user_name2', 20, 'test2 log entry message')
print("last_id.....",last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'WAIT', 'f-name, last-name', 0, 'Waiting for start... ')
print("last_id.....",last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name', 1, 'Processing running... ')
print("last_id.....",last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'RUN', 'f-name, last-name', 2, 'Processing Paused... ')
print("last_id.....",last_id)
Log.newEntry(last_id, 'PAUSE', 'f-name, last-name', 2, 'Processing Resumed... ')
print("last_id.....",last_id)
sleep(2)
```

**This is the output from the test code**

```
newID.... 12  
newEntry =========================
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
newID.... 13
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
last_id..... None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newLog function does not return a value.  Change the last line of the function to the below.

```
return query.createLog(fk_user_preferences, recipe_name, user_name, message)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!